# Best Way to Test an API in PHPUNIT Without Revealing Private Credentials

Tags: php, api, phpunit

I created a PHP class that consume's AskGeo's API. (http://askgeo.com)

I want to test it with PHPUNIT and include those tests in the PSR package I am releasing, but I don't want to give away my Account ID and API key that I will need to test the API.

What's the best way to do this?

I was thinking I could include a config file that could be filled in with those credentials before running tests.

Is that the best way?

Answer (score 2):

Good unit tests must be fast and repeatable. If you make your tests work with remote API, you will break this rules:

- HTTP request is too long to execute - never know how long, good tests work for milliseconds
- once customer have unstable internet, test results may differ. And tests will not work without internet at all.

What you may do is to separate your code to your logic and some transport layer. You should inject transport into logic code, to be able use real transport (like cUrl) for production and mock transport for testing env. Mock transport should return answers from fixtures you provide. This will make tests extremelly fast and always produce same result.

Transport layer can look like this:

- `TransportInterface` with method `request($url, $params, $method, ...)`
- `StubTransport implements TransportInterface` with `__construct($fixtures)` - if $url+$params+$method found in fixtures, return result.
- `CurlTransport implements TransportInterface` - cUrl implementation.
- `VoodooMagicTransport implements TransportInterface` - get results using some black magic.

You logic code: `FantasticLogic` class with `__construct(TransportInterface $transport)`. Do not use implementation's class name in parameter type, only interface.

Comment: OP didn't state that he wants to unit test the class. Looks like he wants to implement integration tests.

Comment: He is releasing package. It seems more logical, that integration tests should create package customers, using their accounts to askgeo.

Comment: Thanks guys. It makes sense not to test against the real API.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, that is the best way if you really want to test against the live production API on each test run -- to require the developer that is utilizing your class to enter in their own credentials. However, if there isn't a proper set of credentials available, you should consider using a stub (a static canned answer to the call).